# In HTML form "required" attribute is not working

Tags: html, css, frontend

For the textarea , the field doesn't tell that is required to be filled and user can save the form with empty text area.

```
<tr>
    <td>Summarys&nbsp;
        <input type="text" path="SummaryInfo" id="SummaryInfo" style="text-align: right" size="5" maxlength="5"  onkeypress="if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) (event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;"  onkeyup="javascript:this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" required/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Does your input exist within a `<form>` element? How is the form submitted?

Comment: Please at least take the time to format the code in your post correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's `input`, not `html:input`

Also add a type to your input, like `<input type="text" />`

Comment: I changed it to  '<input type="text">' but still the same. I am able to save the form without typing anything in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error. Instead of html:input just input and required will then work.

```html
<tr>
  <td>Summarys&nbsp;
    <form action="/">  
      <input type="text" path="SummaryInfo" id="SummaryInfo" style="text-align: right" size="5" maxlength="5"  onkeypress="if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) (event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;"  onkeyup="javascript:this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" required/>
      <input type="submit">
    </form> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

And an important hint from @Max Alexander Hanna. Don't forget the type.

Comment: As I mentioned above - I changed it to '<input type="text">' but still the same. I am able to save the form without typing anything in the text field.

Comment: @Tsunde00 and you change the input tag ? `<input ..`instead `<html:input ..`?

Comment: Yes I change the input tag

Comment: @Tsunde00 are you wrapping your input field in form tags. see my example. `<form><input></form>

Comment: Also submiting form should be with `<input type="submit">` button

Comment: @GîrbuNicolae Yes of course